# Should you use smart pointers in C++ for low-level data structures, like for example, Linked Lists? A use case could be an interview setting

Tags: python, c++, list, linked-list, smart-pointers

I have already implemented a templated Linked List which uses unique pointers internally.
First I create a **ListNode** struct that holds this pointer to the next node and the data. Finally, it also has a handy function to turn it to string (for printing later on):

```
template < typename T>
struct ListNode;

template<typename T >
using ListNodePtr = std::unique_ptr<ListNode<T>>;

template < typename T>
struct ListNode
{
    ListNode(T data) : data(data) {}
    T data;
    ListNodePtr<T> next = nullptr;

    std::string str()
    {
        std::string output;
        ListNode<T>* curr = this;
        while (curr)
        {
            output += std::to_string(curr->data) + " ";
            curr = curr->next.get();
        }
        return output;
    }
};
```

The linked list itself stores a smart pointer to a node, which contains all other nodes. Several methods with basic list features have been implemented like **inserting** an element, **deleting** at position n, or **reversing** the list.

```
template <typename T>
    class LinkedList

{
public:
    LinkedList() = delete;
    LinkedList(const std::vector<T>& data)
    {
        createListFromVector(data);
}

void createListFromVector(const std::vector<T>& data)
{
    if (data.empty())
    {
        return;
    }

    ListNodePtr<T> head = nullptr;
    ListNode<T>* curr = nullptr;
    for (const auto& item : data)
    {
        if (!head)
        {
            head = std::make_unique<ListNode<T>>(item);
            curr = head.get();
            continue;
        }

        curr->next = std::make_unique<ListNode<T>>(item);
        curr = curr->next.get();
    }

    m_list = std::move(head);
};

// insert node at head
void insertNode(T data)
{
    ListNodePtr<T> newNode = std::make_unique<ListNode<T>>(data);
    newNode->next = std::move(m_list);
    m_list = std::move(newNode);
}

// delete the nth node
void deleteNode(int pos)
{
    if (pos < 1) { return; }

    ListNode<T>* curr = m_list.get();
    while ((pos-1) && curr)
    {
        curr = curr->next.get();
        --pos;
    }

    if (curr)
    {
        ListNodePtr<T> next = std::move(curr->next->next);
        curr->next = std::move(next);
    }
}

// reverse the list iteratively
void reverse()
{
    ListNodePtr<T> prev = nullptr;
    ListNodePtr<T> curr = std::move(m_list);
    ListNodePtr<T> next = nullptr;

    while (curr)
    {
        next = std::move(curr->next);
        curr->next = std::move(prev);
        prev = std::move(curr);
        curr = std::move(next);
    }

    m_list = std::move(prev);
}

void print() { std::cout << str() << std::endl; };
std::string str() { return getHead()->str(); }
private:
    ListNode<T>* getHead() const { return m_list.get(); };
    std::unique_ptr<ListNode<T>> m_list = nullptr;
};
```

As you can see, I implemented some basic functionality in this way, however, this seems way too convoluted, when compared to how I would do this in Python, for example. Things would be so much simpler without being restricted to a **unique_ptr**.

For example, suppose I want to make a method:
**toOddThenEven** which rearranges the elements in the list - first all odd positions, then all even positions: **1**, 7, **2**, 14, **5**, 32 becomes 1, 2, 5, 7, 14, 32. The first index is considered to be **1** and therefore, **odd**.

Normally one can accomplish this easily by making some copies of the head of the odds, the head of the evens, and then two more pointers for moving forward through the list. At the end, you can have the odds list: **1->2->5** and the evens list: **7->14->32**, which can be merged together by setting the **next** pointer of the last odd index element to the head of the evens, and returning head of the odds.

Example in Python:

```
def toOddThenEven(node):
if not node:
    return None

headO = node
headE = headO.next 
curr = headO
nxt = headE

while(nxt and nxt.next):
    # skip adjancent element for both curr and nxt
    curr.next = curr.next.next
    nxt.next = nxt.next.next

    # move forward
    nxt = curr.next.next
    curr = curr.next

# concatenate odds list and evens list
curr.next = headE
return headO
```

Now, there is probably a better way to implement this, but, nevertheless, you probably need to make some temporary copies as I've done above, in order to make it work without exploding your brain.

Therefore, a C++ solution, would be to use **shared_ptr**s instead of **unique_ptr**s. HOWEVER, in this case, we would use 2 times the memory, for each pointer, thus making our LinkedList data structures NOT OPTIMAL - when compared to a simple implementation of just using raw pointers with **new**/**delete** and **RAII**, such that the user's of our data structures will not be concerned with managing it's memory directly.

So, in case of designing such a data structure - especially when time is short (such as during an interview setting, or demonstration purposes to other developers) it seems like **raw pointers** are the better choice in this case. Either that or **shared_ptr** if you don't care about the extra performance hit. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would use raw pointers in a case like this. Of course C++ code is going to be a bit more intricate than Python code, because Python is garbage collected, so there is no issue with releasing allocated memory.

Comment: I wouldn't use smart pointers to implement a linked list.   I'd use the standard templated container type `std::list` which offers a lot of characteristics (defined complexity of specified operations, etc) that are offered by a (properly implemented) linked list.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I would too, but in an interview setting you may not be allowed to rely on std::list, or when teaching the concepts of a linked list to others.

Comment: @Ron normally I agree with you, if you have a higher-level class to implement. But does this apply to low level data structures as well? Is there much value in using smart pointers at all, in this case? Or does it just serve to increase the complexity of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I can actually answer this myself, I was just hoping others would share their perspectives on this topic.

In general it is best to keep things simple during something like an interview setting. In addition, low-level data structures are usually implemented without the use of smart pointers, as even the C++ standard library is not using them, for example for std::list.

In addition, interview sources/websites like Leetcode also have the given code snippets using raw pointers.

Moreover, I would also like to mention that normally I would use smart pointers when doing development. As it is very rare that you have to design your own low-level data structures.

If prompted, I would continue to give some examples of smart pointers and contrast them, i.e: **unique_ptr** vs **shared_ptr** vs **weak_ptr**.

Finally, if they would ask me to use smart pointers I would probably go with **shared_ptr** at first, as it would be simpler. Perhaps I would also define a shorter name with the **using** clause.